# python csv writer to write source code snippets to a single cell

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to write source code snippets from scripts and other relevant information to csv file, where each cell would contain one piece of information.

Desired output would be like:

```
function name, number of lines, source code
helloWorld, 3, {
               printf("hello, world\n");
               }
fooBar, 5, {
           const char *foo = "Hello";
           const char *bar = "World!";
           fprintf(stdout, "%s %s\n", foo, bar);
           return 0;
           }
```

where each source code snippet should be in a single cell while preserving the code structure.

Below is the code:

```
with open('functionInformation.csv', 'wb') as csvOut:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvOut, delimiter = ',')
    csvwriter.writerow(['function name', 'number of lines', 'source code'])
    for functionObject in functionObjectRepository:
        csvwriter.writerow([functionObject.funcName, functionObject.numLines, functionObject.sourceCode])
```

where functionObject is the object with attributes like the name of the function (funcName), number of lines of code (numLines), and the actual source code (sourceCode).

Output I am getting right now looks like:

```
helloWorld, 3, {
printf("hellp, world\n");
}
fooBar, ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this site](https://www.fir3net.com/Programming/Python/how-do-i-create-a-multiline-cell-csv-file-within-python.html):

> 1. newlines are represented with a carriage return/newline,
> 2. the string should be wrapped in quotes.

It then shows the example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import csv

multiline_string = "this\nis\nsome\ntext"                # assign string
multiline_string = multiline_string.replace('\n','\r\n') # convert newlines to newlines+carriage return

 with open('xyz.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
      w = csv.writer(outfile)                            # assign csv writer method
      w.writerow(['sometext',multiline_string])          # append/write row to file
```

However, replacing all `\n` with `\r\n` in your code would also change the ones in the code itself. So maybe you'll have to find some better way to do the change.

Comment: Have you watched for the line `fprintf(stdout, "%s %s\n", foo, bar);`, to see if the `\n` inside is also being replaced? As each line of code is separated by a semicolon, maybe you should replace `;\n` with `;\r\n`.